# Pass a json input to API using requests

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I need to pass a json object as input to an API which will give me back a json in return.

The usual way I access an API using requests is

```
response=requests.get('url',auth=uauth,headers=headers).json()
```

This will give me the json output from the API. Here, I pass the parameters dynamically in the url. I just need to pass a JSON input here so that I can get a response for that particular input.

Comment: For querystring parameters or POST data see jheld's answer below. If you want to modify other parts of the url use `format`

Answer (score 0):

For `requests.get`, you can just pass your input data in like so `requests.get(some_url, your_data_input_object, ...)`

Please see docs: [Requests Passing URL Parameters](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/?highlight=json%3D#passing-parameters-in-urls)

You can use `json=your_python_json_like_object`, for when doing `requests.post`.